# how to cast collision avoidance constraint as a convex one to avoid getting errors

Tags: cvxpy

I am running a trajectory optimization problem using sequential convex programming where at each iteration I solve a QP problem. I am linearizing my inter-vehicle collision avoidance constraint as the following:

[image]

However, when I do this I get an error from CVXPY complaining that my constraint does not follow DCP:

```
s_cvx = cvx.Variable((11, 12))
u_cvx = cvx.Variable((10, 6))
for k in range(N):
  if k>0:
          dist_linear = cvx.norm(agent_i_q-agent_j_q,2) + \
                      (agent_i_q-agent_j_q/cvx.norm(agent_i_q-agent_j_q,2)) @ (s_try[1,0:3]-s_try[1,6:9])
          constraints += [dist_linear >= 0.5]
......
```

where `(s_cvx[k,0:3]-s_cvx[k,6:9])` refers to the current difference in position between the two vehicles and `agent_i_q,agent_j_q` refer to their positions in the previous iterate.
The DCP error is as follows:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP:
0.5 <= Pnorm(var1216896[0, 0:3] + -var1216896[0, 6:9], 2) + (var1216896[0, 0:3] + -var1216896[0, 6:9] / Promote(Pnorm(var1216896[0, 0:3] + -var1216896[0, 6:9], 2), (3,))) @ (var1216795[1, 0:3] + -var1216795[1, 6:9]) , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  var1216896[0, 6:9] / Promote(Pnorm(var1216896[0, 0:3] + -var1216896[0, 6:9], 2), (3,))
0.5 <= Pnorm(var1216896[1, 0:3] + -var1216896[1, 6:9], 2) + (var1216896[1, 0:3] + -var1216896[1, 6:9] / Promote(Pnorm(var1216896[1, 0:3] + -var1216896[1, 6:9], 2), (3,))) @ (var1216795[1, 0:3] + -var1216795[1, 6:9]) , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  var1216896[1, 6:9] / Promote(Pnorm(var1216896[1, 0:3] + -var1216896[1, 6:9], 2), (3,))
......
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is impossible to write a lower bound for distance as a convex problem. You might need to find a solver that supports nonconvex QPs, and not use CVXPY.

Comment: (Also I guess you meant ``-0.25`` in the last constraint)